# Making a request to API on keyup but I cant access something in the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ive been trying for the past couple of hours but for I can't seem to figure out why I can access $scope.FeatureGroup to add to my url

Any ideas?

```js
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate',]).controller('repeatController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope;
  $scope.FeatureGroup = 50000;
  $scope.ShowMeData = function($scope){
    var url = 'URLHERE' + $scope.FeatureGroup;   
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) { 
      console.log(data);
      //$scope.Object = data;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-repeat-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ngRepeat">
    <div ng-controller="repeatController">
      There are  Features - Please click them to see the page:
      <br><input type="number" ng-model="FeatureGroup" ng-value="10" ng-keyup="ShowMeData()">  
      <br><input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter Features..." aria-label="filter friends">
      <ul class="example-animate-container">
        {{FeatureGroup}}
        <!-- ngIf: Objects.length === 0 -->
        <!-- ngRepeat: feature in Object | filter:q as results -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to call `{{ FeatureGroup }}` from within an `ul` element (browsers tend to not like that), try it in a `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of following line. You are overriding the $scope variable:

```
 $scope.ShowMeData = function($scope){
```

You are really not passing any scope variable while calling the function

```
ng-keyup="ShowMeData()".
```

Just change it to:

```
$scope.ShowMeData = function(){
```

and it should work.

Comment: Ahh you beauty! Thanks so much :)